# Magento 2 : Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error:

Tags: exception, url-rewriting, magento2, categories

I have moved one magento 2 website from one server to another, after configuration, I got below error on category pages:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mageplaza\Core\Helper\AbstractData::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /SOME_PATH/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /SOME_PATH/app/code/Mageplaza/Core/Helper/AbstractData.php on line 56

Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mageplaza\Core\Helper\AbstractData::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /SOME_PATH/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /SOME_PATH/app/code/Mageplaza/Core/Helper/AbstractData.php on line 56
```

I have **tried** below things to resolve above:

1. Reindexing
2. Re-save category pages from backend
3. Created new category, and found its page working fine.

It seems there is a problem with database where old category urls need to be reindexed/rewritten or processed some way.

Can anyone help me to resolve this or any guide how I can troubleshoot this further?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `var/di` directory resolves the problem. I didn't need to run any CLI command nor I need to do any cache clear stuff!